# Adding into Cumulative Files

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a cumulative file with 291170 records.  In my new table that needs to be added to the cumulative file there are some account numbers that are already in the cumulative file, and some that are new accounts.

All i want to do is merge these variables on (delqsep12, queuesep12) to those accounts that in there but add all the variables that are originally in there for account numbers that arent already in there, they will just be blank.

so cumulative file (cummu12) has

```
account_number, netpayjun, netpayjul, netpayaug , delqsep12, queuesep12
```

and the added file I want to merge in just has

```
delqsep12, queuesep12
```

So at the end I should have 295519 rows, new account_numbers have been added and those already those have just been updated with the new variables.
Also these new variables may have something in them for old accounts but some may be empty.

Comment: I don't really understand your question: is `cummu12` a flat file or a database table? If it's a table, have you looked at the [MERGE command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx)? If it's a file, what format is it in (csv, xls, txt)?

Comment: Are all `account_number` values unique in `cummu12`? Does the new table really have just those two columns, `delqsep12` and `queuesep12`? Or does it also have `account_number`? I mean, there should be a way to tell whether a row in your new table represents a new account or an existing one.